# White noise approach to Feynman integrals: why do we use this renormalization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, renormalization, path-integral, stochastic-processes, wick-theorem

I start by saying that I know very little about Feynman integrals so please bear with me.

In Kuo's book "White noise distribution analysis" or in Hida, et al. "White noise analysis" there are discussions regarding the connection between the Feynman integrals and the White noise theory.

In particular they discuss the informal object

$$\exp \bigg\{c\int_0^T \dot B(s)^2 ds\bigg\}.$$

Of course this object is not well defined and one must "renormalize" it.

They define a renormalized version (as a Hida distribution) by means of its S-transform:

$$S\left(\mathcal N \exp \bigg\{c\int_0^T \dot B(s)^2 ds\bigg\}\right)(\xi)=\exp\left(\frac{c}{1-2c}\int_0^T \xi(s)^2 ds\right).$$

I am curious about the fact that this renormalization does not coincide with the one obtain by considering the Wick versions, i.e. the object defined by

$$S\left(\exp^{\diamond}\bigg\{c\int_0^T \dot B(s)^{\diamond 2} ds\bigg\}\right)(\xi)=\exp\left(c\int_0^T \xi(s)^2 ds\right).$$

In general in the White noise context when we want to renormalize an object we take the Wick version, sometimes denoted using the notation $:\cdot :$, but in this case they do not, why is this?